# Change pushViewController animation direction

Tags: xcode, animation, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

i read alot about faking the animation of pushViewController, but I'm wondering if there is a way to change the actually animation, because I would like to use the navBar and the BackButton of the navigationController.
Currently I'm using this to animate:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:YES];
[views setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height -40)];
CGRect frame = views.frame;
frame.origin.y = - self.view.bounds.size.height;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"viewSlideUp" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
views.frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

but I get an overlapping effect, so my view isn't sliding up, the view is sliding away to the top left side.

Has anyone dealed with that problem? Thx for any kinda help!